# Six distinguishable fair dice are rolled.What is the probability of getting exactly $3$ pairs.

Tags: probability-theory

Six distinguishable fair dice are rolled.What is the probability of getting  exactly $3$ pairs.

As, they are distinguishable, I consider they have different colors.

The total number of cases would be $6^6 * 6!$

Number of favourable cases would be=${3 \choose 1}{6 \choose 1}2!+{2 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1}2!+{1 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}2!$

As, we are choosing the first pair by ${3 \choose 1}$ ways and the number of the first pair in common in ${6 \choose 1}$ ways and multiplied them by $2!$ as they have different colors.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose the first pair to be formed from the dice. There are 6 values for that pair. Then there are $\binom{4}{2}$ many of the remaining dice that can be chosen for the second pair, and again 6 values for that pair (assuming  that 4 equal dice are allowed, as they do form pairs). The last pair si then determined and also has 6 values (under the same caveat).

So there are $\binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{2}\cdot 6^3$ throws that are good, among $6^6$ total (no need for an extra $6!$). The quotient is the probability.